# To show Create and detail view in one view using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

Hi i want to show a page where i'm allowing user to create a new record and show the other related records of same table below .....

i need to add data in Hobbydetail class:
       public class HobbyDetail
    {

```
public virtual HobbyMasters Hobbymaster { get; set; }
public virtual Course course { get; set; }
public virtual StudyMedium StudyMedium { get; set; }
public virtual decimal Fees { get; set; }
```

}

I want my view "Create" to let the user create a new record and to also to show  existing record below it...
I Dont want to use a viewmodel...
Can sumbody help me
Thanx in advance

Comment: @glosrob: I followed this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136560/how-to-show-two-partials-view-data-on-index-cshtml-mvc3
But it does help me to save my data...through this all i get is a null object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is: In your controller, create a child action that renders the list, then render that action in your "Create" view using [Html.RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607) (also [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839451.aspx)). I have included some code below (I have not tested this, but it should give you the basic idea). Please note this is not the only way to accomplish this - You could use a partial view [see this](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/). Please also understand the difference between html.RenderAction and html.Action, [see this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

```
    //In HobbyDetail Controller
    [HTTPGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
      var model = new HobbyDetail ();
      return View(model);
    }

    [HTTPPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HobbyDetail model)
    {
      if(ModelState.isValid)
      {
         //logic to persist model
      }
      else
      {
         //logic when validation fails...
      }
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult ListAll()
    {
      List<Hobbydetail> model = //query to DB, or Data store to get Hobbydetails
      return View(model);
    }

//View for ListAll
@model List<HobbyDetail>
{
 Layout = null; //No layout here...
}

<ul>
@foreach(var h in Model)
{
 <li>@h.HobbyMasters.Name</li> //for example...
}
</ul>

//View for Create
@model HobbyDetail 
...
@{html.renderAction("ListAll");}
```